# SQL Stored Proc - Replaced CASE with IF, now not filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We had an issue generating IDs using MAX(idcolumn) + 1 (very heavily paraphrased) where two requests inside half a second generated the same number for two rows, so I have created a Sequencer which works as intended. However, I can't use NEXT VALUE FOR inside a case expression, so I've had to rejig the statement quite heavily. The relevant part of the code used to look like:

```
INSERT INTO
[other columns]
VALUES
[F_ID]      
    CASE
        WHEN @P_StartDate = NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE COALESCE(@F_Id , 
            (SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(F_Id AS Int)) AS nvarchar(7)) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = d1.M_Id AND ISNUMERIC(F_Id) = 1 and M_Flag = @M_Flag), 
            (SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(F_Id AS Int)) AS nvarchar(7)) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = d1.M_Id AND ISNUMERIC(F_Id) = 1), 
            (SELECT CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(F_Id AS Int)) + 1,1) AS nvarchar(7)) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(F_Id) = 1))
        END ,
FROM dbo.TABLE1 as d1
WHERE d1.D_UID = @OriginalD_UID
```

I replaced that with:

```
DECLARE @NEWF_ID nvarchar(7)

    IF @P_StartDate IS NULL
        SET @NewF_ID = NULL
    ELSE IF @P_StartDate IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN   
        IF @F_Id IS NOT NULL
            SET @NewF_Id = @F_Id            
        ELSE IF (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id AND M_Flag = @M_Flag) IS NOT NULL        
            SET @NewF_ID = (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id AND M_Flag = @M_Flag)     
        ELSE IF (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id) IS NOT NULL
            SET @NewF_ID = (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id)          
        ELSE 
            SET @NewF_ID = CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR F_Id_Sequence as nvarchar(7))        
        END

INSERT INTO
[columns]
VALUES
[@NewF_Id]
FROM dbo.TABLE1 as d1
WHERE d1.D_UID = @OriginalD_UID
```

And where the CASE expression was in INSERT INTO, it is now just @NewF_ID. I was unable to use d1.TABLE1 in the new iteration, but I can't see why it isn't filtering. I don't believe I've changed the inherent logic.

Some guidance would be very appreciated.

Update:

Thanks for everyones comments. It turns out the M_Id was not being declared properly until further down in the procedure. I solved this by:

```
DECLARE @NEWF_ID nvarchar(7)
DECLARE @M_ID nvarchar(7)

SELECT @M_ID = M_ID FROM dbo.table1 WHERE D_UID = @Original_D_UID

    IF @P_StartDate IS NULL
        SET @NewF_ID = NULL
    ELSE IF @P_StartDate IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN   
        IF @F_Id IS NOT NULL
            SET @NewF_Id = @F_Id            
        ELSE IF (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE @M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id AND M_Flag = @M_Flag) IS NOT NULL       
            SET @NewF_ID = (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE @M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id AND M_Flag = @M_Flag)        
        ELSE IF (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE @M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id) IS NOT NULL
            SET @NewF_ID = (SELECT MAX(F_Id) FROM dbo.TABLE1 WHERE @M_Id = dbo.TABLE1.M_Id)         
        ELSE 
            SET @NewF_ID = CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR F_Id_Sequence as nvarchar(7))        
        END

INSERT INTO
[columns]
VALUES
[@NewF_Id]
FROM dbo.TABLE1 as d1
WHERE d1.D_UID = @OriginalD_UID
```

Simple fix in the end, but ultimately a good learning experience with stored procedures.

Comment: Curious how you have `is not null` but also `= null` which will never be true

Comment: Why are you storing your `SEQUENCE` as an `nvarchar`? `SEQUENCE`s can only be numerical data types. Is it intentional that the value `2` has a greater value than `198`?

Comment: you can do INSERT INTO
[columns]
SELECT
[@NewF_Id], [some other columns]
FROM dbo.TABLE1 as d1
WHERE d1.D_UID = @OriginalD_UID